# Is Jannah open now?

Tags: jannah

Is The Promised Paradise open now for those who have earned entrance? Or must everyone, who has gained entrance, wait until Judgement Day?

Answer (score 0):

According to the verses and narrations, the promised heaven and hell exist right now and will be fully presented in the Akhirah. According to his actions, beliefs, and morals, man will be led to his eternal place.
Some verses to confirm the existence of heaven are as follows:

1. Al-Shaykh al-Saduq says: "And our belief about heaven and hell is that they both exist now and have been created, and the Prophet entered heaven during his "Isra' and Mi'raj" and saw hell there."
2. [3:133]/[3:131]/[53:14-15] these verses say that hell and heaven have been created and prepared.

see more [here](https://www.islamquest.net/fa/archive/fa1798)